# Convergence study of a series of functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am studying the convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (x^n)}{(1+x)^n}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb R$.

My initial approach was to use the ratio test, but I am not getting to anything conclusive. I have also thought that if the $|\sin x^n| \leq 1$, then I would only need to study the convergence of $\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$, but I do not think this is very rigorous. I have pretty much run out of ideas I'm afraid.

Can somebody tell me how to prove if the above series converges?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yep!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+0+to+sin(x%5En)%2F(1%2Bx)%5En&f1=sin(x%5En)%2F(1%2Bx)%5En&f=Sum.sumfunction_sin(x%5En)%2F(1%2Bx)%5En&f2=n&f=Sum.sumvariable_n&f3=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit%5Cu005f0&f4=infinity&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2%5Cu005finfinity)

Comment: There is a theorem which states that if $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n $ and $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n $ are both convergent, then $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nb_n $ is convergent. You *might* find that useful, since it is clear that $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(1+x)^n} $ converges, if $ \frac {1}{|1+x|} \le 1 $. In fact, you know its value: it is $ \frac {x+1}{x} $.

Comment: but the sine function diverges between -1 and 1, so according to that theorem, the series would not converge would it?

Comment: Wait, how do you know that $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin (x^n) $ always diverges?

Comment: $a_n = b_n = (-1)^n/\sqrt{n}$ individually converge and product series of $1/n$ diverges -- that theorem is not true with conditional convergence.

Comment: @AhaanRungta well imagine that $x = -1$. Then doesn't the series diverge, since $\sin[(-1)^n]$ oscillates between negative and positive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that $|\sin (x^n)|\le |x^n|$ to estimate $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|\sin (x^n)|}{|1+x|^n}\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left| \frac{x}{1+x}\right|^n,$$ from which you can conclude that if $\displaystyle |x/(1+x)|<1$, then the series converges absolutely. In particular it converges for all $x>-1/2$.

On the other hand, if $|x|>1$ then the estimate used above is worse than the one you wrote: $|\sin (x^n)|\le 1$, using which we get (absolute) convergence if $1/|1+x|<1$. The new piece of information from this inequality is convergence when $x<-2$.

Thus at least you can say that the series converges (absolutely) if $x>-1/2$ or $x<-2$.